# echo con php de un formulario action=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF]

Tags: php

No soy capaz de crear un formulario con echo( ) en PHP.

He probado no se cuantas combinaciones y no se cual es el caracter que falla.

```
   echo  "<div class='central'>
            <div class='login'>
            <div class='titulo'>
                Consultar
            </div>
            <form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars(".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].");?> 
            method='post' accept-charset='utf-8' id='loginform'>
                <input type='email' name='usuario' placeholder='Usuario' required>
                <input type='submit' title='Ingresar' name='Ingresar'>Consultar</input>
            </form>
          </div>   
      </div>";
```

Se crea el formulario pero despues de $_SERVER algo me falla :

[image: formulario]

Comment: En (action=) te falta abrir y cerrar las comillas (action = ') y cerrarlas (' method=), Te sugiero que siempre que tengas problemas de ese tipo, mires el código fuente y no el resultado, normalmente es ctrl + u ahí lo habrías visto de inmediato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es la parte que está mal:

```
<form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars(".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].");?>
```

Estás abriendo un bloque php con esto: `<?php` pero ya estás en un bloque php que empieza con el `echo` inicial.

Usa [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.printf.php) y todo será menos confuso:

```
printf("<div class='central'>
            <div class='login'>
            <div class='titulo'>
                Consultar
            </div>
            <form action='%s' method='post' accept-charset='utf-8' id='loginform'>
                <input type='email' name='usuario' placeholder='Usuario' required>
                <input type='submit' title='Ingresar' name='Ingresar'>Consultar</input>
            </form>
          </div>   
      </div>",
      htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

Simplemente, con `printf()` se pondrán marcadores para todos los valores que provengan de variables u otras funciones, para este caso, en la parte del `action` pusimos un marcador `%s`, y luego, ponemos el valor al final: `htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`, eso hará que el marcador `%s` sea reemplazado por ese valor. Esto se puede hacer con diferentes valores, poniendo los marcadores respectivos y los valores al final, separados por coma. Lee la documentación y los ejemplos de código que hay allí para que entiendas como funciona `printf()`, te será de gran ayuda en situaciones como estas.

Finalmente, cabe decir que existe también `sprintf()`, que funciona del mismo modo, a diferencia de que en vez de mostrar el resultado lo guarda en una variable y es útil cuando estás concatenado contenido por ejemplo.

Comment: Cedado muchas gracias de nuevo! Que interesante. Hasta ahora no me habían hablado de los marcadores de este tipo.